# How do I reference my site's title in a template?

Tags: wagtail

I'm starting a Wagtail site. In the admin section, I went to Settings >> Sites >> localhost, and set "Site name" to "My first Wagtail site."

How do I display the site title in templates using Django code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tag to use is:

```
{{ request.site.site_name }}
```

Answer (score 5):

Old version

```
<h1>Welcome to the {{ request.site.site_name }} website!</h1>
```

new version

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}
{% wagtail_site as current_site %}

<h1>Welcome to the {{ current_site.site_name }} website!</h1>
```

Reference: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/releases/2.9.html#upgrade-considerations

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

in wagtail 4.1,use {{page.get_site}} in template.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).